# Get Min Price From Product Variation Table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, group-by, left-join, right-join

Product Table
[image: This is Product Table]

Variation Table
[image: This is variation table]

How do I get a result from Product with every product's min price from Variation?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) [ask] [Help] [mre] [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

I join by description, which should work if no different products have the same description. It would be better to join by something more specific like product_id, but product_table does not have that as a column.

```
SELECT
     p.*,
     v.min(price) as min_price,
FROM
     variation_table v
JOIN
     product_table p ON v.description = p.description;
```

You could probably add `ORDER BY product_id` to do in order of the product ids or whatever other field you'd prefer.

Comment: Thanks For anser
What I execute

SELECT `products`.*,`category`.`name` as `category_name`, `sub_category`.`name` as `sub_category_name`, `brand`.`name` as `brand_name`
FROM `products` 
LEFT JOIN `category` ON `products`.`category_id` = `category`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `sub_category` ON `products`.`sub_category_id` = `sub_category`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN `brand` ON `products`.`brand_id` = `brand`.`id` 
LEFT JOIN 
(
 SELECT `product_id`,  MIN(CAST(`price` AS UNSIGNED)) as min_price
    FROM `product_variation`
    GROUP BY `product_id`
) as pv ON `products`.`id` = `pv`.`product_id`